# DtdProcessing.Ignore in .net 3.5

Tags: xml, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, dtd

In .net 4.0 we can use property `XmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing` with value `DtdProcessing.Ignore` for ignore dtd. In .net 3.5 we can use only `XmlReaderSettings.ProhibitDtd` without ignore-value. How activate ignore mode for dtd in .net 3.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try following:

```
XmlReaderSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;

XmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver = null;

XmlDocument.XmlResolver = null;
```

works for me